# app can't be installed with SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, storekit

With codes below SKStoreProductViewController can present descriptions of an app.

When I touch the "free" button it shows "install app". Then I touch "install app", a progress bar shows inside the app icon. However the progress bar disappear in 2-3 seconds and the app remain uninstalled.

It's my demo app. Does anyone know the reason?

```
SKStoreProductViewController *skvc = [[SKStoreProductViewController new] autorelease];
skvc.delegate = self;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"425349261" forKey:SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier];
[skvc loadProductWithParameters:dict completionBlock:nil];
[self presentViewController:skvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Are you testing on a device or simulator?

Comment: @bbodayle I'm testing on an ipod.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem ist that you don't really connect to the Itunes store instead it's the special sandbox store environment. I had the same problem and you need to have a test account and do the purchases with that one instead of your normal itunes account.

It's all described here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html

Comment: thanks, it works! I have another question, when the app distributed to users, how apple knows it's not for development?  I tested it with distribution certificate without test account, apps couldn't be download also.

Comment: the signature changes as soon as the App is in the Appstore and thats how apple knows that now it should connect to the real appstore.  I would recommand the "Selling Products with Storekit" video that you'll find here : https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Answer (score 2):

When you try to install app from sandbox make sure that you had logged out from your current account.