# Cannot install apps from storekit productview

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, storekit

I'm developing an iPhone app using Appcelerator Titanium SDK and created module based on https://github.com/atsusy/TiStoreProductView/ to display an app using Storekit framework. The problem is I can't install any app from the product view that being displayed from my app. When tapping on the green 'Install' button, the installation process seems to started but stopped later without any error message. If re-tap the 'Install' button, it immediately stop installation.

Is there any configuration or info.plist settings that I need to set in order to enable my app to install other apps using Storekit?

Comment: you cannot install an app from your app on iOS

Comment: then StoreKit productview sole purpose is to view the app only, not install?

Comment: I guess so. I don't know the module. However, my statement is a fact about iOS.

Comment: however there's an app: "Drippler" could install other apps from their app using storekit ProductViewController. that's why I'm wondering if I'm missing something.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/drippler-updates-tips-apps/id619307903?mt=8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer: [SKStoreProductViewController can't download app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409049/skstoreproductviewcontroller-cant-download-app)
And some explanation here: [app can't be installed with SKStoreProductViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004357/app-cant-be-installed-with-skstoreproductviewcontroller)

Short answer: It will work after app being released to app store